# How to let Xcode 7.3.1 to recognize custom framework In IB

Tags: xcode, swift

I created a custom framework called `SampleModule`.
The statement `import SampleModule` in a swift file is OK.

There is a class `DWButton(subcalss NSButton)` in SampleModule.
But I am confused.

Why in Interface Builder doesn't appear my framework `name(SampleModule)` in `Module(PopUpButton)`?

Does anyone know how to let Xcode to recognize custom framework?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually type the name of the framework in that module field.